# Error.... Help in Javascript, it is Expo error

Tags: javascript

This is part of my code that it is giving me an error:

```
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="name"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="email"
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                 />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="password"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                />
                <Button
                        onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}
                        title="Signup"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Register
```

Here is the output

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Goat\Project1\components\auth\Register.js: 
    Unterminated JSX contents (44:19)

  42 |
  43 |                         />
> 44 |             </View>
     |                    ^
  45 |         )
  46 |     }
  47 | }
```

Comment: Can you give a more in-depth explanation of what you're trying to do, and what you expected to happen?

Comment: Your code snippet has missing opening braces and parenthesis. Please provide code that reproduces this error.

Comment: where does `Button` import from?

Answer (score 0):

I think so u need to wrap  html by

<> Your html </>

And please also add some more part of you code for better understanding of function and class..